# How to remove icons from the taskbar?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-registry, taskbar, regedit

I have windows 10, and I'm trying to **completely** remove 2 icons. (Not just hide them in the overflowed list.) Here are the 2 items I want to remove:

[image]

So I went to the startup programs (at task manager), and here's what it shows:

[image]

I don't know if it's safe to disable "NVIDIA Backend". Also, there isn't an option for "Safely remove hardware...". So I think the safest, most efficient solution would be to edit the registry, and remove it there. (I don't want to remove the programs, just the icon at the taskbar.)

My question is, how and what should I edit in the registry to accomplish this?

Comment: The icon for "Safely remove hardware" can't be removed.  It only appears when hardware is detected.  You can disable the Nvidia icon through the use of Autoruns or simply uninstall the GeForce Experience.

Comment: It seems safe. Just make sure that if your screens goes kaboom all of a sudden that you connect the VGA (or whatever cord) from the MOTHERBOARD, not the GPU. But until then, keep the cord in the GPU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a long time, I was unable to figure out how to remove Nvida GeForce Experience from the notification icons section of the taskbar.  I even knew how to hide other icons.

I finally came across this solution:

1. Click on Start > Control Panel > Nvdia Control Panel.
2. Click on the Desktop menu, and uncheck "Show Notification Tray icon".

I never would have guessed that Nvida would have its own section within the Windows 10 Control Panel.

Source: http://ccm.net/faq/25176-remove-the-nvidia-control-panel-from-the-system-tray

Answer (score -1):

**To remove an icon from the notification area**

1) Open Taskbar and Start Menu Properties by clicking the **Start** button Picture of the Start button, clicking **Control Panel**, clicking A**ppearance and Personalization**, and then clicking **Taskbar and Start Menu**.

2) Click the **Notification Area** tab, and then do one or both of the following:

- A) To remove **system icons**, under System icons, clear the check boxes of the icons you want to remove.
- B) To remove other icons, click **Customize**, click the icon you want to remove, click the drop-down list that appears next to the icon, click **Hide**, and then click **OK**.

3) Click **Apply**, and then click **OK**.

*Reference : Microsoft.com*

Comment: Did you mean "Taskbar and Navigation"?

Comment: Yes. At task manager.

Comment: So update the answers.  Incorrect or instructions that are not clear are not really all that helpful.